# Find the areaid that sells most number of products but with less discount

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am pretty new to SQL Server.

I have a question on one of the queries that I am trying to come up with

I have a table like this:

```
pid areaid units discount 
-------------------------
1    1      10    10%
2    1      20    10%
3    2      30    5%
4    2      40    15%
5    1      50    10%
6    3      10    0%
```

I am trying to find the `areaid` that sells most number of products(units) but with less discount.

I tried some query as below but I couldn't figure out a way to join the below 2 queries.

I was able to find the least discount using the below query

```
select 
    min(y.discount) 
from
   (select 
        sum(discount) as discount 
    from 
        productinfo 
    group by 
        areaid) y
```

but not sure how to get the area id corresponding to that aggregated discount.

Similarly I figured out a query to return maximum number of products aggregated by areaid

```
select 
    max(y.uomsum) 
from
    (select 
         sum(uom) as uomsum 
     from 
         productinfo 
     group by 
         areaid) y
```

It would be great if anyone can help me with this query.

Comment: It would also be great if you post what would be the desired result for your sample data

Comment: Were you able to find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
SELECT MIN(Y.Discount),MAX(Y.Units) 
FROM
    (SELECT AreaID,SUM(Discount) AS Discount ,SUM(units) as Units
     FROM productinfo 
     GROUP BY Areaid
    ) Y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  areaid, MAX(TotalUnits), MIN(TotalDiscount)
FROM
(
select areaid , SUM(units) as TotalUnits, SUM(discount) TotalDiscount
from Table1
group by areaid
)T
group by areaid
```

Comment: Why use a `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY`?. You also already grouped by `areaid`, what's the point on grouping again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you need to calculate the average discount per area discount, then sum.

```
Select
  sum(discountedUnits), areaid
from (    
    select
      sum(units) as units,
      sum(units) * (1-(convert(float, discount)/100)) as discountedUnits, 
      convert(float, sum(units) * (1-(convert(float, discount)/100))) / sum(units) as averageUnit,  
      areaid, 
      discount
    from
      productinfo
    group by areaid, discount) as g
group by areaid
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fe98/11)

To get the max, you could do a top 1 and order by descending, or put it all in another subselect